# SQL (mysqli) query not yielding results from online database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have an online database with multiple records and am writing a PHP script using mysqli to connect to the database and get records from it.

Here's my script:

```
<?php
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUser = 'root';
    $dbPass = '';
    $dbDatabase = 'XYZ';

    $db = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbDatabase)  or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    $dbFound = mysqli_select_db($db, $dbDatabase) or die('Could not select database: ' . mysqli_error($db));

    $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['userid']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,  $_GET['password']);

    // Select all records

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tableName";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($db)); 
 ?>
```

The query successfully executes but no records are printing in the browser window. Will a simple SELECT statement return records while also printing them on the screen, or do I need another method to actually print the results of the query?

Or, is something else wrong in my code? The script successfully connects to the database and I can also insert values into the database from the script itself, so it seems to only be having an issue with the SELECT queries...

Any help is greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: You need to fetch and print the `$result`

Comment: What tutorial you are learning mysqli from?

Comment: You have to loop through your result if you want to print all of the records.  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { //print records here }

Answer (score 1):

> The query successfully executes but no records are printing in the
>   browser window

That is because you are not doing any print operation.

> do I need another method to actually print the results of the query?

Yes , you need to loop through the recordset.

---

Something like this..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($db)); 

$res = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $res[] = $row;
}
print_r($res);
```